# How to replace an array in Azure template?

Tags: azure-rm-template

I have "onprem' array in templates parameters

```
"onprem":{
            "value":  [
                "1.1.1.0/16",
                "2.2.2.0/16"
              ]     
        }
```

and want to replace this in the template

```
"localNetworkAddressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes":  [
              "1.1.1.0/16",
              "2.2.2.0/16"
            ]          
          }
```

The below gives me an error

```
"localNetworkAddressSpace": {
            "copy": [{
              "name": "onpremBase",
              "count": "[length(parameters('onprem'))]",
              "input": {
                  "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('onprem')[copyIndex('onpremBase')]]"                               
              }
          }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign array value to the property:

```
"localNetworkAddressSpace": {
     "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('onprem')]"
}
```

What you are attempting to do will result in something like this (and your code is not exactly correct as well):

```
[
   {
       "addressPrefixes": "1.1.1.0/16"
   },
   {
       "addressPrefixes": "2.2.2.0/16"
   }
]
```

Property iteration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#property-iteration